# How do i create a second logger that logs to file in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a logger in my `Startup` configure method:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory ) {
    loggerFactory.AddConsole( Configuration.GetSection( "Logging" ) );
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddFile(@"C:\Some\Path\portal-{Date}.txt");
```

I have created a BenchmarkFilter Class that implements `IActionFilter.` It will run some performance benchmarks on Action Methods when enabled. I can pass this a logger via DI but i need this to log to a new file location, in a csv format. How would i go about this? My Class so far:

```
public class BenchmarkFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly bool _isBenchmarkOn;
    private string _benchmarkFilePath;

    private Stopwatch _stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public BenchmarkFilter(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _isBenchmarkOn = appSettings.Value.EnableBenchmarkLogging;
        _benchmarkFilePath = appSettings.Value.BenchmarkFilePath;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (_isBenchmarkOn)
        {
            _stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (_stopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            _stopWatch.Stop();
            var seconds = _stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            //logging to do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the built-in **Log Filtering**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering) capability. Seems like you could set rules to output the Authorization filter logging to a specific provider.

Comment: I cant quite work out how i could use that to pass a different logger (To a file) to the BenchMarkFilter, should i be able to?

Comment: Actually you don't pass a different logger, the idea is you create & configure multiple log providers one of which is your special CSV version. You then configure your CSV log with a filter that only listens to your custom authorization filter messages and records only those.